# Is it possible to start a text selection, jump to another page without moving the caret, and then end the selection range with shift-click?

Tags: microsoft-word, selection

Is it possible to start a text selection, jump to another page without moving the caret, and then end the selection range with shift-click?

If I use the navigation pane, or the "Go to" command, the caret moves, and my contiguous text selection is cancelled.

Dragging the vertical scroll-bar, or using the scroll wheel will move the view-port without moving the caret, but these methods are slower and more tedious.

---

I tried another way with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Find:

- I copied some text from the end of my text range.
- In the navigation pane, I heading-jumped to the beginning of my text selection.
- Then, I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Find with the copied text to try to go back to the text selection end.
- This doesn’t work in Word, as the caret still moves.

On the other hand, Find and replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> does not break the text selection in Google Docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a method to do this in Word.

Comment: Saying something isn't possible can be the right answer, but that, alone, leaves the reader with a question of whether you're correct or just aren't familiar with a  solution. This kind of answer is always better if you can cite a source.